# "make -f ../tools/certs/Makefile.selfsigned.mk cluster1-cacerts" not working on my windows

Tags: istio

Please I encountered the following error while installing istio for multi-cluster communication. Can anyone help please?

[Failed to generate cluster1 cacerts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pFjgG.png)

For each cluster, I want to generate an intermediate certificate and key for the Istio CA